# Why can't Groovy find my file?

Tags: groovy

I wrote a script in groovy to find files java test files recursively in a given directory with certain names, the concerned part of the code is:

```
def projectRootDirectory = args.length ? new File(args[0]) : new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
        def srcFilesCount = 0, testFilesCount = 0, srcLinesCount=0, testLinesCount=0
        def srcFileSubstringPattern = '.java'
        def testFileSubstringPattern = 'Test.java'

        projectRootDirectory.eachDirRecurse() { dir ->
             dir.eachFile {
                 if (it.name.endsWith(testFileSubstringPattern) || it.name ==~ /Test.*java/ ||
                         it.name.endsWith('Tests.java') || it.name.endsWith('TestCase.java')) {
                     //println "Test file found: " + it.name
                     testFilesCount++
                     it.eachLine { testLinesCount++ }
                 } else if (it.name.contains(srcFileSubstringPattern)) {
                     srcFilesCount++
                     it.eachLine { srcLinesCount++ }
                 }
             }
         }
```

It finds already existing files in the repo which was cloned using SVN that match for example `someTestCase.java`, but when I created some new ones by using the command `touch dummyTestCase.java` via Cygwin in Windows 7 or via the Windows 7 explorer `right click -> New -> Text Document` option and rename it to something like `TestDummy.java`, it doesn't find them. The script also treats copies of the respective files the same way i.e. it finds copies of old files that already existed but not the new ones I create. I even opened up file permissions to fullest on the newly created files, but no change. Whereas the BASH `find` command via Cygwin always finds all the files without any issue. I have confirmed using diagnostic print statements the the script is looking in the correct directory. I even confirmed this by having the script create some files there and confirmed they got created in the correct place.

Comment: Can you show your  finding files code?

Comment: Can you put the code that loads the files from directory. Normally nothing wrong with above, unless there is some issue with upper or lower case.

Comment: @aristotll I edit the question to show more code.

Comment: The code works fine in my computer.

Comment: @aristotll What operating system do you have and how did you create the new test files? I am on windows 7 but used the touch command within Cygwin.

Comment: @AnonymousHuman Maybe it is because of Windows? I use mac, and create the file by `touch` command and manually copying.

Comment: @aristotll Weird, if I create the new files in Windows explorer, it works. Maybe Cygwin has some weirdness going on since it's an emulator. Thanks for the confirmation research.

Comment: Quick question - does the problem occur for recursively stored files or files at the root dir level?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak Both, and I'm also finding that it's happening on files I created in Windows explorer too now. But using the BASH find command never fails.

Comment: Try adding a println it.name at the beginning of the eachFile loop just to see if it's the OS/Groovy or the code after that is filtering them out.  Also, using your code, a file that you just "Touched" wouldn't have any lines so I'm not sure it would have any effect on the result.

Comment: @BillK Thanks for that tip, I used it and saw that nothing prints. In the test directory I have two *.java files so it should have printed two names. Regarding what you said about lines of code, true that newly created files don't have lines BUT the files should still be seen by Groovy shouldn't they?

Comment: Yes groovy should see them.  I use that eachFileRecurse behavior a lot and have never seen the problem  you describe.  I tend to think it's the OS.  Could you also add a println dir.cononicalPath (I think that's the name, probably misspelled) above the dir.eachFile to make sure you are reading from the directory you think you are reading from?

Comment: @BillK Weird, I had it print the value of the variable `projectRootDirectory` and that showed the correct path but adding the print statement you said, I added `println "Directory canonical path: " + dir.getCanonicalPath()` and it shows NOTHING, it is as if this line of code doesn't execute! And debug isn't letting me set a break point on this line in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @BillK Wait, I think I see the issue. Creating a sub dir. inside the root dir. being analyzed by the script and then putting some dummy files there I see the script sees them, so it's only files at the root level that aren't seen. I don't think I knew this detail well enough yesterday when SzymonStepniak asked about this. Which means starting with eachDirRecurse isn't seeing root level qualifying files. Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, the answer turned out to be amazingly simple. I replaced `eachDirRecurse` with `eachFileRecurse` thus also eliminating the nested loop. Thanks a ton to all the comment authors whose help led me to this discovery.